# How to parse string containing vectors to actual vector

Tags: rust

I have a string that I'm reading from input stream:

```rust
"['App01', 'App02', 'App03' , 'App04']"
```

What's the most efficient way to convert it to a `Vec<String>` type in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) answer:

```rust
serde_json::from_str(&s.replace('\'', "\"")).unwrap()
```

But both `replace` and `from_str` have to copy the strings data so memory wise it's probably not the best.

Comment: You call it code golf, but this is honestly better than ad-hoc splitting on commas. Unless you're going to full Raku and write a custom ad hoc grammar for it, "make it fit into JSON" is not a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to parse a string like this, and it depends what you mean by "efficent" (performance? lines of code?), but here's a possible solution:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = "['App01', 'App02', 'App03' , 'App04']";

    // Start by removing the surrounding braces.
    let trimmed = input.trim_matches(['[', ']'].as_slice());

    // Make the vector by:
    let vector: Vec<String> = trimmed
        .split(',') // separating the string parts by the comma
        .map(str::trim) // cleaning each part by removing surrounding space
        .map(|item| item.trim_matches('\'')) // then removing the single quotes
        .map(String::from) // and converting each item from a slice to an owned String
        .collect(); // and putting it all into a vector

    println!("{vector:#?}");
}
```

And its  output:

```
[
    "App01",
    "App02",
    "App03",
    "App04",
]
```

That's assuming you truly want an owned String. But it'd be a bit better if you opted to use a reference instead. To do that, it'd look like this instead:

```rust
let vector: Vec<&str> = trimmed
    .split(',') // separating the string parts by the comma
    .map(str::trim) // cleaning each part by removing surrounding space
    .map(|item| item.trim_matches('\'')) // then removing the single quotes
    .collect(); // and putting it all into a vector
```

Notice that the `.map(String::from)` call is gone and the resulting type is `Vec<&str>`. This avoids duplicating the strings and instead just uses a reference to the original input, using less memory overall.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This fails if any of the strings themselves contain commas.